# Clarification for exercise 1-10 in Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm asked to prove that if

$T:\mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$

is a linear transformation, there exists a number $M$ such that

$\|T(h)\|\le M\|h\|$ for $h\in \mathbb{R}^m$.

I'm not sure whether I'm being asked to show that such a number (that is independent of $h$) exists or to  show that such a $M$ exists for  each $h$.  Can someone please clarify?

Comment: Note that if $M$ could depend on $h$, the statement would be really really obvious -- for any real numbers $x$ and $y$, there exists an $M$ such that $x \leq My$...

Answer (score 4):

You are being asked to show that such a number exists which is independent of $h$.

**Hint:** Note that, since $T$ is linear, you need only show that there is some $M$ such that $\|T(h)\|\leq M$ when $\|h\|=1$. Furthermore, the set $\{h:\|h\|=1\}$ is compact.

Comment: But we need to show $T$ is continuous. And to show $T$ is continuous, we need to show $|T(h)| \leq M |h|$.

Answer (score 1):

It actually says "show that there is a number $M$ such that...". So yes, you are supposed to find a single $M$ such that the inequality is satisfied for every $h$.

Answer (score 1):

I think we can interpret the sentence in two ways as follows:

1. There exists (a number $M$ such that $\|T(h)\|\le M\|h\|$) for $h\in \mathbb{R}^m$.
2. There exists a number $M$ such that ($\|T(h)\|\le M\|h\|$ for $h\in \mathbb{R}^m$).

But I want to interpret as (2), because (2) implies (1) and because (2) is true.

Let $K := \max\{|T(e_1)|, \cdots, |T(e_m)|\}$.
Note that $|h_i| \leq \sqrt{h_1^2 + \cdots + h_m^2} = |h|$.
Then, the following inequality holds:
$$|T(h)| = |T(h_1 e_1 + \cdots h_m e_m)| \leq |T(h_1 e_1)| + \cdots + |T(h_m e_m)| = |h_1| |T(e_1)| + \cdots + |h_m||T(e_m)| \leq K (|h_1| + \cdots + |h_m|) \leq K m |h|.$$

Let $M := K m$.

Then, for any $h \in \mathbb{R}^m$, $$|T(h)| \leq M |h|.$$